# Disable Address space layout randomization (ASLR) for my processes

Tags: linux, memory, non-root-user

I want to run some programs in Linux where I want to disable Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). I know to disable it at system level, which is by setting `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` to 0.

However, I don't have access to change the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` as I don't have the administrator rights and the administrator would also not accept my request to do so. So I want to only disable it for my own processes. Is it possible?

Comment: LOL, this was migrated and the SO dupe that was not got more upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238457/disable-and-re-enable-address-space-layout-randomization-only-for-mysef

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do it like this:

- Write a program that forks
- After the fork you should do something like

  ```
  int old, rc;
  old = personality(0xffffffff); /* Fetch old personality. */
  rc = personality(old | ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE);
  if (-1 == rc) {
      perror("personality");
  }
  ```
- And then `exec` your program

Comment: Or just use `setarch`

Comment: @ninjalj Didn't know about `setarch` :)

Comment: How do I check if it worked? Any command to print out the settings? @ninjalj